# Difference between an entity and model - in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, entity

Could someone please explain the core difference between an entity and model in mvc, this does not include view models.

Answer (score 1):

An entity is a thing of interest to an organisation about which data is to be held. In a business for example, entities would be items such as a customer, an employee, or item of stock. Each of these entities have what are described as Attributes.

Model represents 'concepts' (entities) and relationships between them.

Comment: Concepts? And relationships between them? This makes me picture conceptual classes that have associations (navigation properties - ef). Are these really models?